# Image path issues in my order list Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on order module in Laravel 8.The issue I'm facing with my product image path.

Here is screen shot of my issue:

[image]

When I remove these brackets from image path it works OK:

Blade file code:

```
<h4>My Cart</h4> 
@foreach($mem as $t) 
  <div class="top-cart-item"> 
     <div class="top-cart-item-image"> 
       <a href="#"><img src="{{URL::TO('')}}/storage/app/{{$t->proimage}}"></a>     </div>
 </div>
 @endforeach
```

[image]

Comment: Post your blade file code.

Comment: <h4>My Cart</h4>
                                    @foreach($mem as $t)
                                        <div class="top-cart-item">
                                            <div class="top-cart-item-image">
                                                <a href="#"><img src="{{URL::TO('')}}/storage/app/{{$t->proimage}}"></a>
                                            </div>

Comment: Please put your view code here as well.

Comment: <h4>My Cart</h4> @foreach($mem as $t) <div class="top-cart-item"> <div class="top-cart-item-image"> <a href="#"><img src="{{URL::TO('')}}/storage/app/{{$t->proimage}}"></a> </div>      my view code for image

Comment: @AwaabJaved checkout my below answer once and let me know if it is helpful to you

Comment: if you don't mind could you please tell me why you want to place those brackets in your URL?

Answer (score 0):

Change your image tag from

```
<img src="{{URL::TO('')}}/storage/app/{{$t->proimage}}">
```

to this

```
<img src="{{asset('/storage/app/$t->proimage')}}">
```

Comment: getting the same bracket issue but when i remove the brackets image appear ok

Comment: @AwaabJaved it is because the value which you are passing from controller already have that brackets

Comment: sorry for late reply.....but is issue is resolved....thank u